# Дает ли htmlspecialchars полную неуязвимость к XSS?

Tags: php, javascript, html, xss

Здраствуйте. 
Можно ли полностью убезопасить страницу от XSS через input если при помощи htmlspecialchars преобразовать все "<" и ">" на соответствующие спецсимволы `&lt;` и `&gt;`? 
Или всё же есть какие-то иные спецсимволы, котрые браузер будет считать за "<"">"?

Comment: Важно исключительно через input? Бывают же и другие случаи - https://m.habrahabr.ru/post/211494/

Comment: «считать за» — такого не бывает, но XSS вовсе не только в этих двух символах